# How can I read a pdf with Firefox 5?

Tags: pdf, firefox

I'd like to upgrade Firefox to the new version but I don't know if I'll still be able to read pdf on it with this [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/firefox-mac-pdf/). Is there another way ?

Comment: (Now that firefox is moving to a quicker release cycle, they will need a new extension model. Making me upgrade and check compatibility with each release can be brutal.)

Answer (score 1):

The [PDF Browser Plugin from Schubert|it](http://www.schubert-it.com/pluginpdf/) recently added support for Firefox.
It's free for personal, non-commercial use.  I've found it to be a very capable in-browser PDF viewer.

Comment: I've just tried and this extension and it is not compatible with FireFox 5.

Comment: It doesn't appear to support searching. That's basically a show-killer for me. Bummer, too. It renders much better than anything Open IT Online offered.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for a long time, and couldn't really find anything. I use the Open IT Online addon now instead—I like that it is integrated into the Download file dialog and gives an option to Open IT Online in addition to saving and opening in Preview. It supports opening in Google Docs, Zoho, and a few other services.

Comment: Hmmm... it appears to require a Google Docs login. Updating answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Acrobat, in the preferences you can set to open in web or open in Acrobat.

If you choose web, it will open in FireFox

If you choose Acrobat, it will download the .pf and open in Acrobat

This is currently the way I will do it as Firefox has gone from Firefox 4 to FireFox 10 beta. The reason is to catch up with IE in releases. (apparently)